# How to execute jython script for every 120 seconds in IBM WebSphere Application Server in linux?

Tags: linux, websphere, jython, websphere-8

```
def generate_Dump_File(type_name, server_name):

    #print 'Server Name:'+ server_name
    server = '/Server:'+ server_name
    # Set the Node ID
    serverID = AdminConfig.getid(server)
    #print 'Server ID:' + serverID
    if serverID  == "" :
        print "Server Name you have entered does not exist"
    else :

        jvm = AdminControl.queryNames('type='+type_name+',process='+server_name+',*')

        print "####################################"
        print "Generating Heap Dump..................\n"
        AdminControl.invoke(jvm, 'generateHeapDump')

        print "Generating Java Core Dump..................\n"
        AdminControl.invoke(jvm, 'dumpThreads')


        print "Generating System Core Dump..................\n"
        AdminControl.invoke(jvm, 'generateSystemDump')


generate_Dump_File(type_name, server_name)
```

This is the code I am executing in WAS
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/

The above path where i am executing this script 
But i need execute those script for every 120 seconds, above script i am getting input from user.. In cron tab is not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the code below to execute jython script for every 120 seconds to generate dump in IBM Websphere

`def print_time( threadName, delay):

    while 1:
            time.sleep(delay)
            print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

              execute code here
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread", 120, ) )

except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
while 1:
   pass`

Above code works fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

You could loop within the script after you've done a one-time lookup of the server ID.

```
import time
while true: 
  time.sleep(120)
  ... existing code...
```

Comment: where i have to put the code before the def generate_Dump_File or  after the else condition??? @covener

Comment: I added the code `while true:` . it displaying the error as Nameerror: true: